# Ability to add div element next to chart using plotly.js

Tags: reactjs, plotly

I am trying to add an external div element(Summary Panel) on the right side of the bar chart I have implemented using react-plotly.js.
[image]

The div element would pop-up next to the chart when onClick event is fired on the chart. The panel would display the information related to the bar that was clicked. The data object based on which the bar chart is created is:

const barData = [
    { endTime: '', startTime: '', duration: 6, initiatorUsername: 'abc', title: 'abc1', aTitle: 'Manager', outcome: 'Success' },
    { endTime: '1521203405', startTime: '1520389805', duration: 7, initiatorUsername: 'defs', title: 'Senior Analyst', aTitle: 'Manager', outcome: 'Failure' }
];

I haven't seen any such example or any documentation related to add external div element to the chart. Is it possible to link chart to the external div element ?
I did attempt to implement it by doing the following:

```
<Plot
                    data={this.prepData(timelineData)}
                    onClick={(data) => {
                        this.renderCustomPanel(data);
                      }
                    onHover={(hover) => this.getHoverInfo(hover)}
                    type={'bar'}
                    layout={layout}
                    style={{ width: '95%' }}
/> 

renderCustomPanel(e) {
        const panelInfo = timelineData.map(i => `<span className="panel-info">
        <span className="tooltip-value" style='font-size:15px;display:block'>${i.duration} days <br> Start time: ${moment.unix(i.startTime).format('MMM-DD-YYYY h:mm:ss')} <br> End time:${moment.unix(i.endTime).format('MMM-DD-YYYY h:mm:ss')}</span></span>`);
        return panelInfo;
    }
```

The onClick function does call the function but doesn't display the div element. I did try applying css styles to the element but nothing works. Firstly, how do I make a panel display onClick?

Alternate solution that comes to my mind is to make panel a separate sibling component. In that case, How do I pass the data to it such that in the description section it displays the information related to the bar that was clicked ?

```
class SummaryPanel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isActive: true
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
            <div className='summaryPanel'>
                <Card
                    label='Summary panel'
                    heading=''
                    description=''
                    />
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" onClick={() => this.hideAlert()}><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>

    );
  }
}
```